# Raw audio format efficiently compressing exact silence

Tags: file-formats

Is there any standardized format for raw audio which very efficiently compresses silence (e.g. decided by a parametrizable energy threshold)? I think this could be solved by some sort of custom RLE-encoding, but I wonder, are there any standardized format with existing encoders/decoders.

If we have audio with a lot of silence (which is very frequent with multi-person conference call audios), then this format can be intermediate target for decoding the original well-compressed audio (especially if more processing like speech recognition is done down the pipeline).

Could I in theory somehow use FLAC as target format and force it to use only `verbatim` and `constant` modes? (prior to that, force silence to be exactly zero by passing the signal through some shrinking operation) It appears so from the issue I submitted to `flac`: https://github.com/xiph/flac/issues/656, but I wonder if there are any other standardized formats for achieving the same? e.g. do any container formats (such as ogg or mkv/mp4/webm) support storing a PCM stream with missing segments / gaps (which would correspond to silence)?

Thanks!